# Iframe and absolute positioned elements

Tags: javascript, iframe, position, absolute

I have a small issue with absolute positioned elements inside of iframe.

So I have a page, on the page I have a iframe with small game. In the game is a guy and the guy has absolute positioned pupils. The pupils are moving by javascript. 
Everything works just fine, but if I open that page, and go ahead and browse other pages in different tabs, After I come back the pupils are on other place than before (completely ut form eyes.)

There are more elements positioned absolutely in that iframe and none have the same problem I guess it is because of the Javascript animation. Did someone encouter similar problem? Im sorry but for many reasons I cannot post the page here.

I can post script for pupils animation:

```
function eyes_sides(){
    $('.eyes').animate({
            left:parseInt($('.eyes').css('left'))-9
        },{duration:1500});
    $('.eyes').animate({
            left:parseInt($('.eyes').css('left'))
        },{duration:1000});
}

function eyes_roll(){
    $('.eyes').animate({
        left:parseInt($('.eyes').css('left'))-7,
        top:parseInt($('.eyes').css('top'))-18
      },{duration:1800});
    $('.eyes').animate({
        left:parseInt($('.eyes').css('left')),
        top:parseInt($('.eyes').css('top'))
      },{duration:1300});
    }

function animate_eyes(){
      var animation = random_number(1,2);
      //alert(animation);
      switch(animation){
        case 1:
          eyes_roll();
          break;
        case 2: 
          eyes_sides();
          break;  
      }
      var delay = random_number(4000,12000);          
      window.animateEyes = setTimeout(function(){animate_eyes()},delay);
    }
```

The script is not perfect, but does what requires.

I was thinking what could cause the problem, and maybe it is somehow connected to that animation runs when the tab is not active? Maybe adding "onBlur" and "onFocus" to stop / start animation would help?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: I think you'll need that `onBlur()`. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112671/settimeout-speeds-up-with-multiple-tabs

Comment: Ok so I have tried the fixes from the other question, and some more with blur and focus, but none helped. I guess onblur and focus doesnt have much of an effect with iframe. any other ideas?

Comment: It does not deql with focus and blur. Try to create a div as iframe's backround.

Comment: Do you mean that `onblur()` did not work with `IFRAME`? You need to set it for the `IFRAME` element itself in that page which contains the iframe, not to the code inside iframe's document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is supposed to stop the animation. At least it triggres `onblur` on your `IFRAME`. You'll figure out easily, how to start the animation again.

I'm not familiar with jQuery, but you can "translate" the code.

```
window.onload=function (){
    var ifr=document.getElementById('your_iframe');
    (function (x){x.onblur=function (){clearTimeout(x.contentWindow.animatedEyes);return;}}(ifr));
    return; 
}
```